# Batch file to find specifc filenames inside folders and copy them to other place

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a directory c:/go  , inside go there is tons of folders, subfolders and files.

I need to find inside go, files that start with net*.inf and oem*.inf , and copy the folder, subfolders and all files where they are to another palce at c:/

please help.. thanks

It can also be vbs or any other way to run on the fly using windows...

Comment: Does it have to be a batch script? You might get more answers if it could be VBScript, Powershell, or Python.

Comment: it can be vbs as well I need something ready to run on windows ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BAT files are appropiate for iterating over the contents of a directory with the `FOR` command. See `HELP FOR` and `HELP SET` and try this

```
for /r %%a in (net*.inf) do (
  echo XCOPY %%~pa*.* \destination
)
```

Repeat the same for `oem*.inf`or any other specifications you need.

After testing, remove the `ECHO` and adjust the `XCOPY` parameters to your appropiate requirements.

**EDIT:** per OPs comments, changed `%%~fa` to `%%~pa` to copy the complete folder content,

Comment: I`m not sure if you got what I said.. I need to copy the fodler and subfolds (if exist) that the .inf are... for example...if you have c:go/go2/net.inf i need to copy the go2 folder and everything inside go2

Comment: `%%~fa` is the fully specified filename of `%%a`, see `HELP SET`.

Comment: ok using for /r %%a in (net*.inf) do (
  echo XCOPY %%~pa*.* \destination
)   IM getting only the inf files, not they respective folders... :(

Comment: c:go/go2/net.inf Im getting only the net.inf copied 

i need the go2 (and everything inside it ) to be copy

thnaks for helping

Comment: Also, what is %%~pa ? I cant find information abou it (sorry im pretty noob at batch files)

Comment: the ~ modifier is documented in the parameter substitution section of the `HELP CALL` information. `%%~fa` expands to a fully qualified filename; `%%~pa` expands to the path only part of the filename.

Comment: Hello, Thank you ...

With this code I`m getting the .inf files copied, and some error invalid nuber of parameters.. 

for /r %%a in (net*.inf) do (
  XCOPY %%~pa*.* c:\dridri

)
pause

Comment: invalid number of parameters  
/go/Wan Miniport (ike)\*.*

Comment: maybe you need to wrap your parameters with "

Comment: well , this code didnt work at all .. :( I`m getting only the .inf files copied.. no folders and others files inside it.